# Run an application under Tomcat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, tomcat

I have an application that needs to run under Tomcat.

I have installed Tomcat but I don't know where can I put the directory of the project.

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: `$CATALINA_HOME` is where Tomcat is installed.

If the application is a WAR file, just drop it in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and TC will automatically create the web app for you.

If you have all of the contents of the application, you must distribute as so:

The root path of your application: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/newfolder`

Define your web.xml file here: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/newfolder/WEB-INF`

Place compiled class files here: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/newfolder/WEB-INF/classes`

Place dependencies here: `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/newfolder/WEB-INF/libs`

Reference for web.xml:
http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-web-xml.html & http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I created the WAR file and put into /webapps and now I've a folder with the same name of the WAR file
How can I execute it?

Comment: Let say for my example the war extracted a folder named 'test', point your browser to http://server_ip:port_num/test

Comment: In /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps there is a folder named test and if I check it into the manager side, I start it and this is the answer: "FAIL - Application at context path /test could not be started"

Comment: What was the name of the WAR file you placed in the webapps folder?

Comment: the same of the folder